# What is an Android view's measured state?

Tags: android, view

I'm having a hard time finding example usage, or explanations, of the Android View concept of "measured state".

To be clear, this is different from measured width and measured height.  See [in Android docs](http://bit.ly/1cUV4zR).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea is that a View has a desired width and height, which is constrained by two factors.

The first constraint is the parent View to which the View is attached. This will describe the maximum width and size of the View. If the View has asked to be wider or taller than the parent view, then it's measured height and measured width will be constrained such that the values are no greater than the parent's. These values, which can be MATCH_PARENT,  WRAP_CONTENT or a dp value, get converted to measured widths and heights once the parent View's width and height constraints are included. This guarantees that no child is larger than it's parent.

The second constraint comes from the View's siblings, or in other words, from other Views attached to the same layout. The ViewGroup (Layout) will resolve a View's width and height such that it displays correctly. These resolved width's and height's are the values you get from getWidth() and getHeight().

There is a lot of good documentation on the Android development portal. In particular look at the Layout section of the View class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Layout

Edit: Sorry for misunderstanding your question. I've taken a look at the concept of measured state for a view, and I can only find a single documented state: MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL. This leads me to believe that it's use may be very limited and it's existence is primarily for the purpose of future functionality or to be made use of by custom Views/ViewGroups.

The documentation for MEASURED_STATE_TOO_SMALL states the following:

> Bit of getMeasuredWidthAndState() and getMeasuredWidthAndState() that
>   indicates the measured size is smaller that the space the view would
>   like to have.

This leads me to believe that the bit will be set whenever a fixed dp/px value is given to the View which is larger than the parent's width and height and therefore the View's measured width and height will have been scaled down.

If you manage to find more states or additional information as to where it is used, please to update the question. All the best!

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I'm actually asking about "measured state", not "measured width" or "measured height".  I'll update the question to be clearer.